# Get SHA256 hash for Visual Studio Code installer file programmatically

Tags: visual-studio-code, sha256

Is there a web API (or otherwise) which would allow an automatic downloader script to fetch vscode installer's SHA256 hash, for any version of vscode including the latest?
This would allow the script to verify the downloaded files automatically by comparing the hashes.

The hashes, for the **latest** version only, are currently shown in the bottom of the download [page](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) in a folded mode (i.e. it needs to be expanded for the browser to fetch the hashes and show them). This doesn't present an easy way for an automatic script to fetch them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no available API for this so I raised a request to Microsoft and they implemented the following API, which gets the HASH as needed (along with other things).

```
https://update.code.visualstudio.com/api/versions/commit:COMMIT_ID(or version)/PLATFORM/QUALITY
```

Examples:

```
https://update.code.visualstudio.com/api/versions/1.56.0/win32-x64/stable
https://update.code.visualstudio.com/api/versions/commit:c7119ae8b6390a5700f6b28f0f1511d676c96562/win32-x64/insider
https://update.code.visualstudio.com/api/versions/commit:c7119ae8b6390a5700f6b28f0f1511d676c96562/darwin/insider
https://update.code.visualstudio.com/api/versions/commit:054a9295330880ed74ceaedda236253b4f39a335/darwin/stable
```

Example returned value:

```
{"url":"https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/cfa2e218100323074ac1948c885448fdf4de2a7f/VSCodeSetup-x64-1.56.0.exe","name":"1.56.0","version":"cfa2e218100323074ac1948c885448fdf4de2a7f","productVersion":"1.56.0","hash":"ab40232ae7fd669effe6c35ea34948349c273a11","timestamp":1620165132598,"sha256hash":"9719979567f6788bcddc675df29a028e995c2724b7a714280c1e14302c2d6faa","supportsFastUpdate":true}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this doesn't allow you to get the hashes for any version, it would allow an automated script to fetch and work with the latest version hashes.

You can get a JSON file of the hashes and other file/version information from https://code.visualstudio.com/sha?build=stable. This can be put through a JSON parser to extract the data you need.